# How to seed a date field in Laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I've managed to set up a decent amount of seeding for data that needs to be in the database at launch. Everything was easy and working well until I needed to seed a DATE field with a default date.

I've tried the following...

**DatabaseSeeder.php**

```
class SettingsTableSeeder extends Seeder {
    public function run()
    {
        Setting::create([
            'name' => 'Start Date',
            'date' => '2000-01-01'
        ]);
    }
}
```

In my model I've been told adding this *should* fix it, but it didn't.

**Setting.php**

```
protected $dates = [
    'created_at',
    'updated_at',
    'date'
];
```

Everytime I go to run the seeder it throws the error:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
The separation symbol could not be found
Unexpected data found.
Trailing data
```

If I remove the quotes around the date it changes to..

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
The separation symbol could not be found
Data missing
```

Any idea how one goes about seeding a default value for a DATE database field?

Answer (score 12):

If `date` is in the `$dates` array, insert Carbon instance instead of a string:

```
Setting::create([
    'name' => 'Start Date',
    'date' => Carbon::parse('2000-01-01')
]);
```

You'll need to make sure that `Carbon` is available to use at the top of the file:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
```

It is auto-loaded by Laravel/Composer.

Comment: I agree with @Alexey Mezenin

Comment: This still throws an "InvalidArgumentException, The separation symbol could not be found. Unexpected data found. Trailing data" for me. I copied and pasted it exactly. It won't let me use Carbon inside of a create call, but lets me use it inside of DB::table insert call.

Comment: Well it isn't agreeing with it for some reason. Throws that error every time until I comment it out.

Answer (score 1):

Just try inserting the `date` using `Carbon` like,

```
class SettingsTableSeeder extends Seeder {
   public function run(){
      Setting::create([
        'name' => 'Start Date',
        'date' => \Carbon\Carbon::createFromDate(2000,01,01)->toDateTimeString()
      ]);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The given answers by Alexey Mezenin and Jaymin Panchal both still resulted in the trailing data error being thrown.

What ended up working for me was including...

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
```

at the top of the DatabaseSeeder.php file.

Then changing my Setting::create to...

```
DB::table('settings')->insert([
    'name' => 'Start Date',
    'date' => Carbon::create('2000', '01', '01')
]);
```

for some reason I can't use Carbon with the standard Model::create method while seeding, but it works for DB::table('table')->insert.

Comment: what errors are you talking about? I've just tested my solution and it works perfectly.

Comment: Doing exactly your solution still results in a Trailing Data error for me for some reason. Copied and pasted exactly. =/

Comment: well, it works. `parse()` just can't give you this error.

Answer (score 0):

```
$dates= [            
           ['name' =>'Start Date'],
           
       ];

       foreach ($dates as $date) {
           Setting::create($date);
       }
```